# C++/TCL how to invoke tk?

Tags: c++, user-interface, tcl

So I want to exequte TCL code inside my programm. I want it to be capable of reaching some of my C++ functions and classes. So I use [C++/TCL](http://cpptcl.sourceforge.net/). All general TCL to C++ binding works fine for me. But now I want to have some little UI on top (so I have lot on general TCL code that interacts with my app and now I want to add Tk gui to it.) How to create simple tk button inside of the window with some name I want using C++/TCL? I do not want to use C++/TK at all.

***Update***
What have I tried:

Put all Tk (.tcl) files into ../../tk folder and try this... it fails

```
#include <string>
#include "cpptcl.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string script = 
        "package require Tcl 8.5\n"
        "set auto_path [linsert $auto_path 0 [file join [file dirname [info script]] ../../tk]]\n"
        "package require Tk 8.5\n";
    Tcl::interpreter tcl_interpreter;
    tcl_interpreter.eval(script);
    return 0;
}
```

Also I tried stuff like

```
#include <string>
#include "cpptcl.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string script = 
        "package require Tcl 8.5\n"
        "foreach tkFile [glob -nocomplain -directory ../../tk *] {\n"
        "    source $tkFile\n"
        "}\n"
        "package require Tk 8.5\n";
    Tcl::interpreter tcl_interpreter;
    tcl_interpreter.eval(script);
    return 0;
}
```

Which also fails.

Also I tried to put tk85.dll near to my app and call

```
#include <string>
#include "cpptcl.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string script = 
        "package require Tcl 8.5\n"
        "load tk85.dll \n";
    Tcl::interpreter tcl_interpreter;
    tcl_interpreter.eval(script);
    return 0;
}
```

and this

```
#include <string>
#include "cpptcl.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string script = 
        "package require Tcl 8.5\n"
        "interp create slave \n"
        "load {} Tk slave \n"
    ;
    Tcl::interpreter tcl_interpreter;
    tcl_interpreter.eval(script);
    return 0;
}
```

as described [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2437). this also fails.

This

```
#include <string>
#include "cpptcl.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string script = 
        "package require Tcl 8.5\n"
        " interp create a\n"
        " a eval {set argv {-display :0}; package require Tk; button \".b\" -text \"Say Hello\"; pack \".b\" -padx 20 -pady 6;}\n"
        ;
    Tcl::interpreter tcl_interpreter;
    tcl_interpreter.eval(script);
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

compiles and runs but does not show ani window or anething else.(

What to do? How to load Tk?

Comment: What goes wrong?  You get an error?  The UI appears and then the program exits immediately?  No UI, and the program exits?

Comment: some horrable error on line 895 of cpptcl.cc

Comment: No UI, and the program exits.

Comment: You're never processing data arriving from the X server, so the GUI cannot be drawn.  You need to use Tcl's event loop, that's how Tk interacts with the X server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said what fails, but this isn't going to work.  To have a GUI, you need an event loop.

I'd recommend a different approach: make your C++ code into a Tcl-loadable module, then your script can run under `wish` and use both Tk and your objects implemented in C++.

Comment: Cant explain wh but sadly that is not an option for me... I just do not get why if we are allowed to load Tk dinamically into TCL (tclsh) as desctibed [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2437) we cant do it from C++\TCL?

Comment: @Kabumbus: At least the code you are showing, is not using the Tcl main loop.  UI elements won't appear without that main loop (which is overridden by Tk at load time).  See http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/Tcl_Main.html

Comment: @Kamumbus: If you've got a properly configured Tcl/Tk 8.5 installation, dynamic loading will work (it won't necessarily with 8.4 though; getting that supported was an 8.5 feature). But you've still _got_ to run the event loop by doing something that calls `Tcl_DoOneEvent`, directly or indirectly. (Only tclsh and wish can get away without doing it explicitly, and that's because they've got some extra special magic hacks in the background.) If all else fails, run the event loop using the Tcl command `vwait forever`; the `forever` is just an arbitrary variable name.

Comment: Side note: do not run `vwait` twice in the same program if you can possibly help it. Reentering the event loop can cause many subtle problems.